# tExtractJSONField From tFileInputJSON - Talent Open Studio

Tags: java, json, xpath, talend

I am very new to Talend Open Studio for DI. I am trying to read data from the below JSON File :

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "id": "X999_Y999",
     "from": {
        "name": "Tom Brady", "id": "X12"
     },
     "message": "Looking forward to 2010!",
     "actions": [
        {
           "name": "Comment",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/X999/posts/Y999"
        },
        {
           "name": "Like",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/X999/posts/Y999"
        }
     ],
     "type": "status",
     "created_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000",
     "updated_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000"
  },
  {
     "id": "X998_Y998",
     "from": {
        "name": "Peyton Manning", "id": "X18"
     },
     "message": "Where's my contract?",
     "actions": [
        {
           "name": "Comment",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/X998/posts/Y998"
        },
        {
           "name": "Like",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/X998/posts/Y998"
        }
     ],
     "type": "status",
     "created_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000",
     "updated_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000"
   }
 ]
}
```

I want to load three attributes into my table ( id, actions_name and actions_link). So, in the first step (tFileInputJSON) - I tried to do a Loop Json query as below:

[image]

Here, am able to extract the rows as I needed. But, then I used a tExtractJSONField to extract individual fields under "actions" for each "id" using XPath expressions as below:
[image]

I tried several other ways to extract the fields but could not do this. Also, not able to find any correct post in stack overflow and talent forums very relevant to my question. Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange the job like ,
[image]

tFileInputJSON is like,

[image]

tExtractJSONFields is like,

[image]

Then you will get output as,[image]